# Returning ISNULL of SUM with CASE for selecting options

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to return the sum of the values of one column when other column (in the same row speaking) is true. But, I can´t achieve...

I am trying the next ones, but no one looks to be correct.

Can I get a pinch of help here? Thanks mates.

```
ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN dbo.TD_MODULO.FIELD1== true THEN dbo.TD_MODULO.FIELD2 ELSE 0 end),0) AS MY_CALCULATED_FIELD1

isnull(sum(if dbo.td_modulo.FIELD1 == true, dbo.td_modulo.FIELD2, 0), 0) as MY_CALCULATED_FIELD2

ISNULL(SUM(CASE dbo.TD_MODULO.FIELD1 WHEN THEN dbo.TD_MODULO.FIELD2 ELSE 0 end),0) AS MY_CALCULATED_FIELD1
```

Comment: What is the type of `TD_MODULO.FIELD1`?

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos Sorry. It was my fault... It is BIT TYPE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is FIELD1 a bit (boolean) field ?, then compare it to 1 or 0

```
select sum(case when FIELD1 = 1 then FIELD2 else 0 end) AS MY_CALCULATED_FIELD1
from dbo.TD_MODULO
```

Answer (score 1):

`dbo.TD_MODULO.FIELD1 == true` this raises an eyebrow. There is no boolean values in SQL Server so you can't simply write true or false (if a literal then `'true'` or `'false'`, if a `BIT` then `1` or `0`), and you need just one equal sign.

The correct expression is a `SUM` with a `CASE`. Assuming that `TD_MODULO.FIELD1` is a `VARCHAR`.

```
SUM(CASE WHEN dbo.TD_MODULO.FIELD1 = 'true' THEN dbo.TD_MODULO.FIELD2 END)
```

You can stack an `ISNULL` on top of it. No need to do an `ELSE 0`, as `NULL` (`ELSE`'s default) won't be added on `SUM()`.